# Reliable Economic Data on China

Tags: data, economics, china, macro

Trying to develop a new strategy, but I need to find reliable economic data on China. It's well known that the official figures there don't tell you everything (to put it nicely), so I was wondering if anyone knows of reliable sources on key macro data such as:

- Credit
- Raw materials production and demand (e.g. copper)
- Durable goods production and demand (e.g. cars)
- GDP allocation (e.g. spending on infrastructure; US exports as a % of GDP)
- Government spending
- Housing
- Personal income

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone who has spent the time and  money on this research would sell it cheaply, if at all.

Comment: Would I be laughed off the site if I mentioned the CIA World Factbook? It could be a tiny bit useful for broad statistics..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the problem with China.   The official data is nonsense, and the estimates of outsiders can change without warning.   Here are some links:

[China Official Stats 1](http://www.stats.gov.cn/english/statisticaldata/yearlydata/YB1996e/B2-10e.htm)

[China Official Stats 2](http://www.stats.gov.cn/english/)

[China Official Stats 3](http://www.stats.gov.cn/english/statisticaldata/yearlydata/)

[More China Stats](http://www.chinability.com/GDP.htm)

[OECD](http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?datasetcode=MEI_CLI&lang=e)

[CIA](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/ch.html)

[World Bank 1](http://data.worldbank.org/country/china)

[World Bank 2](http://web.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/COUNTRIES/EASTASIAPACIFICEXT/CHINAEXTN/0,,menuPK:318956~pagePK:141159~piPK:141110~theSitePK:318950,00.html)

[IMF](http://www.imf.org/external/country/chn/index.htm)

[CMF](http://www.chinamacrofinance.com/)

[Changing Stats 1](http://www.economist.com/node/10329268?story_id=10329268)

[Changing Stats 2](http://www.econbrowser.com/archives/2005/10/china_gdp_stati.html)

[Changing Stats 3 - Copper](http://blogs.wsj.com/chinarealtime/2011/05/20/chinas-doctored-copper-demand/)

[Changing Stats 4 - Copper](http://online.wsj.com/article/BT-CO-20110519-713030.html)

Here are some old charts that might help:

[image]

[image]

I've been trying to track China for a long time.   The first problem is the lack of real data, but the second problem is that China is a communist country.   They don't have to bow to market forces, and they can do some really bizarre things (long term and short term).   They have a lot of situations/policies that aren't sustainable, but it's hard to even guess which path(s) they may take to keep things calm.   The only thing an outsider can do is watch and wait.

Edit 1 =================================================

Oops, I forgot some links and one image:

[Autos 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_industry_in_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China)

[Autos 2](http://blogs.forbes.com/china/2011/05/20/chinas-auto-industry-shows-signs-of-impending-gridlock/)

[Housing 1](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/business/07house.html)

[Housing 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_estate_in_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China)

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the links. Will peruse them. Unfortunately, you're probably right in that all one can do is watch and wait.